# Culture issues in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, culture

I want to display multiple languages and UI cultures on my website. I have enabled the IIS 7 flag which picks up culture from the browser automatically as so:

```
<globalization 
    enableClientBasedCulture="true"
    culture="en-GB"
    uiCulture="auto:en"/>
```

This works perfectly in that the correct Resources files are loaded, and the correct culture is displayed (0.00 for GB; 0,00 for DE).

However this has had an unexpected problem of interferring with my external services, for example here is the code for interfacing with PayPal.

```
var paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType
{
    ItemTotal = new BasicAmountType
    { 
        currencyID = currencyCode,
        Value = basket.SubTotal.ToString("0.00")
    },
    ...
}
```

This code basically creates a string formatted like so `'50.25'`, however as PayPal always requires a dot decimal point, when a culture is selected that has a comma as a decimal point (for example DE - German) the `ToString("0.00")` generates `'50,25'` and so my code fails.

What would be the best method to correct this? I still want the culture set to the user's culture, however I want to set certain parts of my code to use my own culture.

I know I can feed in a specific culture  to the `ToString()` method, but this seems very *hackish*. Any more professional clean approaches?

Comment: Feeding in the specific culture is _exactly_ what you need to do as that's what PayPal requires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
Value = basket.SubTotal.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Here's a link to the overload of ToString() that takes a second System.IFormatProvider parameter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ztz0sa.aspx